# Disable Hyperlink of Master page from content page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AssociateMaster.master.cs" Inherits="EQ.AssociateMaster" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>Employee Quotient</title>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type" />
                <link href="Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
                <script src="Scripts/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <link href="Styles/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <meta name="Author" content="Dharmendra Kumar Singh" />
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
            <!--[if lt IE 7]>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="iefixes.css" type="text/css" />
            <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <script type="text/jscript">
        function clock(){
            var d = new Date();
            var h = d.getHours();
            var m = d.getMinutes();
            var s = d.getSeconds();
            if (parseInt(h) < 10)
                h = "0" + h;
            if (parseInt(m) < 10)
                m = "0" + m;
            if (parseInt(s) < 10)
                s = "0" + s;
            $('#clock').html(", " + h + "<span class='colon'>:</span>" + m + "<span class='colon'>:</span>" + s);
            //  $('.colon').fadeTo(1000, .2);  
            setTimeout(clock, 1000); 

        } 
    </script>
    <body onload="clock()">
        <div id="container">
          <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
             <div id="Div1">
              <h1 style="color:White;"> New EQ <%--<a href="../Associates/Home.aspx"><img style="width: 140px; height: 80px;" src="../images/eq.jpg" alt="" /></a>--%></h1>
            </div>
            </div>
            <form id="search" method="get" action="">
              <div>
              <table>
              <tr>
              <td><asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="16px" ForeColor="White"></asp:Label></td>
              <td><span class="line-separator">&nbsp;</span></td>
              <td>
              <asp:HyperLink ID="SignOut" runat="server"  style="color:White;font-size:15px;font-family:Calibri; background-color:transparent;font-weight: bold;" NavigateUrl="~/Account/EQLogin.aspx">Sign Out</asp:HyperLink></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              <table>
              <tr>
              <td >
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" style="font-family:Calibri;color:White;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;" />
                    <span id="clock" style="font-family:Calibri;color:White;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.3em;"></span>
               </td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div id="menu" >
            <ul>
              <li><a href="../Associates/Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="../Associates/Report.aspx">Report</a></li>
              <li><a href="../Associates/MyProfile.aspx">Profile</a></li>      
            </ul>
          </div>
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphContent" runat="server" />
          </div>
        <div id="footer">
          <div id="footer-left"></div>
          <div id="footer-right"></div>
          <div id="footer-content">
            <div id="footer-navigation">  </div>
            <p>Copyright &copy; DKS  All rights reserved.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the code of my master page and i want to disable all the hyperlinks of this master page from the content page .There is a scenario when we are forcing user to not leave that content page from any ways and for that reason i want to disable all the hyperlinks of this master page.
Please guide me that how i disable this. I am not using Script Manager as i had applied Script manage on every content page and till now developed so many pages so not possible to roll back and apply script manager on master page.

Comment: Do you want to disable them in client side or server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry didn't read your reply about doing it client side... but for server side:

---

You have to put a reference to the MasterPage in your page/user control markup.

```
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="..." %>
```

Then in the code-behind, you just cast the Page.MasterPage to your MasterPage and access its properties.

```
MyMasterPage myMasterPage = (MyMasterPage)Page.Master;
```

Then you can:

```
HyperLink myLink = (HyperLink)MyMasterPage.FindControl("nameOfLink");
myLink .Visible = false;
```

Something along those lines, based on what I've seen before, C# is a bit rusty but the principal is there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do that

```
//disable menu
$("#menu a").each(function(){
   $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

You could similarly add a css class to your logout link and disable that too.

Answer (score 0):

For client side (using JS)

You can use JQuery:

```
$('a').bind("click.myDisable", function() { return false; });
```

That will disable the click event for all hyperlinks.

Call the JQuery using these functions

```
public bool runJQueryCode(string message)
```

{
    ScriptManager requestSM = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    if (requestSM != null && requestSM.IsInAsyncPostBack) {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), getjQueryCode(message), true);
    } else {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), getjQueryCode(message), true);
    }

```
return true;
```

}

private string getjQueryCode(string jsCodetoRun)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {");
    sb.AppendLine(jsCodetoRun);
    sb.AppendLine(" });");

```
return sb.ToString();
```

}

So: runJQueryCode("$('a').bind('click.myDisable', function() { return false; });");

Comment: But how to call this from code behind as in my content page, i am using Script manager .