# Remove DIV from Master Page

Tags: asp.net, html, master-pages

Is there a way to REMOVE a DIV of the master page? not hide, there are some hyperlinks in the div, so I want to remove them from the code as well. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using HTML DOM you can actually remove any element you want. You need to use JavaScript or jQuery to achieve this.

var div = document.getElementById("task_row_" + taskId);
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);

Reference: [Remove DIV tag using Javascript or Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755546/remove-div-tag-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
<div id="random_name" runat="server" visible="false">

content

</div>
```

That will allow you to hide the div, but also from the .net show & hide it as well using.

```
random_name.visible = true
```

The use of Visible, doesn't just hide it from the view but show it in the code, it completely hides it, not view able by the client at all.

For changing content of master page from child page check out my answer from:

[Disable Hyperlink of Master page from content page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12052928/disable-hyperlink-of-master-page-from-content-page/12053296#12053296)

Comment: "visible" just hide the div, user still can see the code. For the .net, how to get the div id of the master page from a child page?

Comment: Visible doesn't just hide the div. ASP.NET doesn't render elements that have the attribute visible=false. I.e. its not sent to the client at all.

Comment: @pita as I and Steve mentioned, if visible=false then the element is not sent to the client at all.

Comment: I just tried, after adding "runat" tag, the visible do remove the code, but the problem still is how to reach a master page's div from a child page on the server side?

Comment: I added more content to my answer, linking to a previous answer I wrote explaining how to access master page element from a child page :)